# Getting the result of the last ChannelInboundHandler

Tags: java, netty

I am writing a client application based on Netty. I would like to extract the result of the last handler in the pipeline.

The pipeline is built with

```java
protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
    if (sslCtx != null)
        p.addLast("ssl", sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc()));

    p.addLast("client", new HttpClientCodec());
    p.addLast("decompressor", new HttpContentDecompressor());
    p.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(HTTP_OBJECT_MAX_SIZE));
    p.addLast("my-handler", new MyApiResponseChannelHandler());
}
```

where the final implementation is

```java
public class MyApiResponseChannelHandler extends MessageToMessageDecoder<FullHttpResponse> {

    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FullHttpResponse msg, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        out.add(msg.status().code() + " - " + msg.status().reasonPhrase());
    }
}
```

I would like to get my hands on the String added to the `out` list.

When sending the request I added code like

```java
ch.writeAndFlush(request).addListener( f -> logger.info("Got value {}", f.get()));
```

and also

```java
ch.closeFuture().addListener( f -> logger.info("Got value {}", f.get()));
```

All of them got me a `null` value.

How can I get the result of the last `ChannelInboundHandler`? I would be happy with a Future, but I can't seem to get the right one.

Comment: Wouldn't you just add another handler at the end of the pipeline that implemented `ChannelInboundHandler` and get the message in the `channelRead` method?

Comment: Those `out` values are for the pipeline. Instead I think you need to set an attribute in `Channel` (`ctx.channel().attr(...)`), then retrieve it in the listener (`ch.attr(...)`).

Comment: @SeanBright - thanks for the response. I am creating the pipeline in one method and invoking the connection in another, so I don't have a direct link between the two.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - that sounds like a good idea, thank you! Attributes seem to be 'Channel-local', so there seems to be no downside to using them. You may want to write this as an answer